# How did Saruman's army reach Helm's Deep so quickly?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, tolkiens-legendarium, the-two-towers

In the *Lord of the Rings* movies, when Saruman sends his army to attack Helm's Deep, he says

> "**This night** the land will be stained with the blood of Rohan. March to Helm's Deep. Leave none alive. To war!  **There will be no dawn for men**."

The army does indeed reach Helm's Deep that same day shortly after dark, which seems impossible.  We see the orcs traveling — a few cavalry on wargs are sent ahead to harass Théoden's ride/march from Edoras to Helm's Deep, but the vast majority of the orc army is on foot.  Judging by the maps in the books (specifically Stephen Raw's revision of the original maps by Christopher Tolkien), the trip from Orthanc (where the orcs start out) to Helm's Deep — even in a straight line — is at least 100 miles.

[image: Portion of a map of Middle-earth, showing Rohan, Gondor and the western part of Mordor, with the scale highlighted and the below locations indicated.]
Key:  1. Orthanc;  2. Helm's Deep;  3. Edoras

In the book *The Two Towers*, Éomer is shocked that Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli have covered 45 leagues (158 miles) in 4 days, over more or less flat ground.  An average human army could cover 100 miles in 3 days — the legendary 101st Airborne set a record in WWII by marching 140 miles in 75 hours, with 34 hours of actual marching time; this wasn't a normal march however, as their commander deliberately set out to break the previous record set by the Japanese.

Granted, orcs on the march rarely rest, and Saruman's army may have had some of the supernatural speed attributed to Sauron's orcs in *Two Towers*, but even if they were as fast as Sauron's orcs, it seems like they couldn't have marched 100+ miles in the 12-16 hours available (it was daytime when they started and they reached Helm's Deep before midnight — hence "This night"; it was winter, so sunrise would have been relatively late — say they left at 9 AM and got to Helm's Deep at 11 PM; that gives them 14 hours).  Théoden's force had an extra day, only traveled half the distance, and many of them were on horseback, but they only beat the orcs to Helm's Deep by a few hours (yes, they had women and children slowing them down, but the women and children actually arrived before the men on horses did).

It has been suggested that I edit this question to expand upon why I think Jackson really was saying that the Orcs made the trip in less than a day, so here we go:  Returning to Saruman's statement — "This night the land will be stained with the blood of Rohan. March to Helm's Deep. Leave none alive. To war! There will be no dawn for men". Note 2 things:

1. It is unlikely that the "This night..." sentence is not directly related to the sentence following it, so it seems safe to assume he is saying the blood will mainly be at HD.
2. The "no dawn" sentence may be metaphorical (e.g., there will be no age of men), but seems more literal — i.e., it is intended to make us remember Gandalf's promise to arrive at dawn on the fifth day.

More generally, Jackson clearly doesn't care whether travel times make sense in relation to distances.  To show what I mean, recall the Ents' attack on Orthanc. The Ent council happens deep in the forest, and afterwards the Ents go their separate ways. Treebeard heads to the edge of the forest, walks north for some time, but then Pippin persuades him to go south, so he does that for a while, then he sees the clear-cut former woodland near Orthanc and he bellows in rage. Seconds later, dozens of Ents emerge from the forest. Where the hell did they come from? If they were all so close to the forest's edge, why didn't they react to the destruction themselves, or mention it at the council?

Other examples of Jackson's relative lack of concern about the plausibility of various details exist as well.  In the books, Legolas occasionally runs out of arrows, and has to find more.  In the films, his quiver is like a machine gun in an action movie — it never runs out, and seems to contain an infinite number of arrows.  In the books, Legolas occasionally misses a shot; in the movies, he literally *never* misses (except when he fires at Gandalf and Gandalf uses magic to destroy the arrow mid-flight — but it seems safe to assume that if Gandalf wasn't a wizard, the arrow would have lodged itself in his skull).  In the books, Frodo is stabbed with a spear held by an Orc; his mithril mail prevents it from piercing him, but the impact causes severe bruising and drives some of the mithril rings so deep into his skin that he bleeds a bit, and the bruises cause serious discomfort and difficulty breathing for days afterwards; in the films, the spear is held by a humongous Cave Troll, and although the impact should have crushed his ribs, he basically passes out for a minute, then recovers completely and doesn't seem to suffer any bruising at all. In short, Jackson didn't care about plausibility and consistency in every detail as much as Tolkien did.

So how did they pull off a 100+ mile march in so little time?  The answer seems to be "They marched 100 miles in less than a day because Peter Jackson said so".  Is there a more satisfactory answer, preferably an in-universe answer?  Or should we chalk this up to "it's a movie, it doesn't have to make sense"?

For that matter, how did the Elves make a much longer march, apparently starting a bit later than the orcs, but manage to beat the orcs to Helm's Deep?  I assume they all came from Lórien, not Mirkwood (Legolas' home) or Rivendell (although they were sent by Elrond of Rivendell, not Galadriel of Lórien, so Elrond must have telepathically ordered Galadriel's troops to go).  This assumption seems safe — just before the elves must have gotten their orders, Elrond and Galadriel were telepathically communicating, and she was basically guilt-tripping him into sending reinforcements; the elf troops are led by Haldir, a servant of Galadriel, not Elrond; and in any case, the trip from Rivendell to Helm's Deep is about 500 miles as the crow flies, far too long for them to reach Helm's Deep in time (although the trip from Lórien to Helm's Deep is still about 250 miles, more than twice the distance from Orthanc to Helm's Deep).  This raises another problem: why did Galadriel — a queen, essentially — need Elrond's permission to send her own troops out (Haldir specifically says he was sent by Elrond of Rivendell, not Galadriel)? But that is a separate issue, worthy of its own question.

Comment: Because Peter Jackson

Comment: It's a mistake to try and assign a consistent chronology to the films. Tolkien took a huge amount of care to ensure that all the dates and distances matched up and made sense, to the point where he had to "rewrite the book backwards", as he says in the foreword. Jackson: not so much.

Comment: Because watching an army marching for 4 days is boring. Note that there's a gap just after we see Elrond. The screen fades to black and when we come up, events have moved forward.

Comment: I think the error here is in assuming that simply because the camera cuts away during the day, then cuts to a scene at night, then the army arrives at Helm's deep in daytime, that what's being presented is a **single 24 hour period.**
Note that he refers to **the land** [of the Rohan] being stained with blood, not Helm's Deep falling specifically.

Comment: @Richard- but Gandalf says he will appear at dawn on the fifth day; the orcs arrive at night on day 4.  Also, we don't see any attacks in Rohan between Saruman's speech and the battle at the Deep, aside from the raid on Theoden's march.  And "march to Helms Deep" means just that - the only part of Rohan between Orthanc and HD is the gap;  in the books Eomer says - long before the battle - that "many months" ago Saruman had "closed the Gap against us", meaning there was no blood to be spilled along the route of march.

Comment: @Richard - and Aragorn is MIA for hours, but sees the army as he makes his way to HD; he says "they will be here by nightfall".

Comment: I always respect your opinion Richard, but it sounds like SSumner and Daniel are on the right track

Comment: We see Aragorn and Eowyn talking.  She asks a question.  Cut to Elrond, Argorn, Arwyn sequence.  Cut back to Aragorn and Eowyn, sh is still waiting for an answer - no time has passed

Comment: Saruman - "This night the land will be stained with the blood of Rohan. March to Helm's Deep. Leave none alive. To war!  There will be no dawn for men".  Note: 1. It is unlikely that the "This night..." sentence is not directly related to the sentence following it, so it seems safe to assume he is saying the blood will mainly be at HD.  3. The "no dawn" sentence may be metaphorical (e.g., there will be no age of men), but seems more literal - i.e., it is intended to make us remember Gandalf's promise to arrive at dawn on the fifth day.

Comment: The cut to Elrond and Galadriel talking telepathically is longer, and leads to a sequence showing Frodo with Faramir, but this suggests to me that all these things are happening at once.  When it cuts back to Aragorn, some time has passed, but we're talking about hours, not days.  Most important of all, we know that 4 days and one night pass between Gandalf leaving and returning - it would be crazy to suggest that he was speaking metaphorically about dawn on the fifth day.

Comment: @Richard - note:  I am watching the extended versions, and no fade-to-black happens.  We see Elrond; hear Galadriel say "...do we let them stand alone?", and the camera cuts to Faramir unfolding a map.

Comment: Well, because of magic!

Comment: @Secko - That does seem to be the answer, but the magic is neither Saruman's nor Sauron's - it is simply "movie magic".  The same movie magic that lets guns hold thousands of bullets, and makes bad guys miss 99.9% of their shots while good guys hit their targets much more easily, and lets everyone go about their business without sleeping, eating, or going to the bathroom.  Seriously - did you ever notice that in epic movies, like Star Wars and LotR, bathrooms don't even seem to exist?  No one poops, pees, or bathes, ever.

Comment: @WadCheber Then why ask the question if you knew already?

Comment: @Secko - I didn't already know.  The comments above from SSumner and Daniel Roseman pointed it out, and now I'm convinced that the Orcs marched 100 miles in less than a day simply because Jackson wanted them to.  But when I asked the question, that thought hadn't crossed my mind.

Comment: @Secko - SSumner's answer probably nailed it: "Because Peter Jackson."

Comment: Saruman's will caused weariness of the heart for the pursuers and lent speed to the Orcs.

Comment: I am sure that Saruman says no such thing in the books, where he remains – until _The Scouring of the Shire_ – rather remote, and we are not privy to his private thoughts, nor do we seem him expressing bloodthirsty aggression, only his attempts to persuade Gandalf and Theoden. Jackson evidently prefers to replace indirect suggestion with in your face demonstration.

Comment: 'Where the hell did they come from? If they were all so close to the forest's edge, why didn't they react to the destruction themselves, or mention it at the council?' Not to mention makes the Entmoot utterly irrelevant/useless in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

J.R.R. Tolkien wrote in *LotR* about the chase of Three Hunters across Rohan (Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli pursuing orcs who took hobbits prisoner). It is written there that "lesser" orcs of Moria were able to do that in three days, and our Heroes could not match that speed.

I see from the map that from Falls of Rauros to Isengard it's close to 300 miles. So it would fit nicely into the narrative. Also, the book mentions about magical/mental influence on orcs, allowing them to increase already phenomenal pace in that march (to Helms Deep that is).

How that works out in the movie? I don't even like to think about it (the movie that is...) If we assume that Jackson was trying to base it on the book, some things would be treated as "assumed". As was in this and in multitude of other cases, the assumption would be explained in one way or other by the book. Contrary to common belief, writing good screenplay off a **big** book is non-trivial exercise, and shortcuts have to be made somewhere. So I'm really not in the business of criticising screenplays, as I sort of get how difficult adaptation work is.

The other side of this coin is Jackson's delusions. The changes to the story which are his own and add only confusion. Like the cavalry charge relieving that keep, like Elven reinforcement and others. Those changes are unnecessary, illogical and inexplicable except for Jackson's thinking he could "improve" story somehow. With results that should not be any surprise.

Oh, one more thing: the Éomer's surprise shouldn't be a surprise. After all, he's talking to Númenórean, Elf and Dwarf. No humans there, so why? Well, maybe the dwarf...

Comment: Worthy of an upvote but the OP was asking about the film. Any insight there?

Comment: Not really except that film shows some consistency with the book. But if the "lesser" orcs can do quite well, Uruk-Hai should be even better (as being stronger and faster?). Book also mentions the magical influence on the orcs on this march from Saruman. Book is still the base for the movie, whatever one might think about it (me! me! I say: "crap"). Does really anything in the film needs to be explained in the film? Either assume some things are left unspoken in the movie (as it's covered by the book) or treat it as stand-alone work. But IMHO second approach is plain mad.

Comment: @AcePL - the book mentions supernatural speed but doesn't clarify the source of this speed (i.e., is Saruman or Sauron responsible?).  And even with this magical speed, the Three Hunters actually manage to shorten the Orcs' lead, until Saruman uses magic to inflict weariness of heart upon them, and forcing them to rest.  Prior to that, the Hunters were gaining ground; even afterwards, they were only a day or so behind the Orcs, despite the fact that the Orcs rarely rested for more than an hour or two.

Comment: @AcePL And the "lesser Orcs" (from the Misty Mountains) were reluctant at best to run during the day - they actually said "We **can't** run in the sunlight".  They did so anyway, mostly so Ugluk wouldn't kill them, but the book does say that when the sun went down, "The Isengarders [and] the soldiers of Mordor lifted their heads and... began to put on speed", suggesting that even Saruman's and Sauron's Orcs were a bit slower during the daytime.

Comment: @Richard - Does Saruman not say the "This night..." thing in the book?  If he does say it, the question could just as easily be answered using the books.

Comment: @WadCheber - This night they enter the *lands* of Rohan. A quick glance at the map would suggest that this could be accomplished easily, and within a day of travel.

Comment: @Richard - They might, but who would they find?  Whose blood would stain the land?  The Gap is closed, and it is implied that even Eomer doesn't venture near Isengard, so surely civilians have fled from areas within a day's march of Isengard as well.  Eomer says he has withdrawn the people of Rohan "beyond the Entwash", presumably not in the direction of Isengard.  And I'm still not convinced that Saruman didn't mean "get to Helm's Deep tonight", which means any attack along the way would increase the length of the march without increasing the time available to complete it.

Comment: @Richard - You effectively made the speed of the march MORE problematic, because the Orcs would have to make side trips and/or take a longer, less direct route to HD.  So instead of marching 100 miles in a day, they have to march 150 miles in a day.  It would be safer to say "despite evidence to the contrary, te march lasts more than a day, ad the blood which Saruman spoke of as being spilled 'this night' was that spilled by the warg riders"

Comment: @WadCheber - This is assuming they did it in a day, an assertion I'd say is frankly dumb since you can actually see their marching pace in several shots. Even if they traveled at a consistent 5mph, it would still take them 20+ hours to arrive and another 10+ hours to form up into regiments and armies.

Comment: @Richard - Which is exactly why I asked the question.  I still think that we're expected to believe that the Orcs marched to HD in less than a day;  I just think the only explanation that makes sense is "It's a movie and it doesn't have to be plausible - it only has to be dramatic and exciting".  The same is doubly true of Elves starting out some time AFTER the Orcs do, marching 2 1/2 times FARTHER than the Orcs do, yet somehow managing to arrive at Helm's Deep BEFORE the Orcs do.

Comment: @Richard - to show what I mean, recall the Ents' attack on Orthanc.  The Ent council happens deep in the forest, and afterwards the Ents go their separate ways.  Treebeard heads to the edge of the forest, walks north for some time, Pippin persuades him to go south, he does that for a while, then he sees the clear-cut former woodland near Orthanc and he bellows in rage. Seconds later, dozens of Ents emerge from the forest.  Where the hell did they come from?  If they were all so close to the forest's edge, why didn't they react to the destruction themselves, or mention it at the council?

Comment: @Richard - Tolkien shows a nearly Obsessive-Compulsive level of attention to detail in his writing.  He took great pains to ensure that distances, travel times, etc, made sense.  Peter Jackson did not - he was concerned with dramatic effect and keeping the audience interested.  So in Jackson's LotR, Orcs can march 10 miles an hour, Elves can march 30 miles an hour, Ents can miraculously emerge from deep in the forest in seconds, Legolas' quiver can hold an infinite number of arrows, and so on. None of this makes sense, because Jackson didn't care if it made sense - even though Tolkien did.

Comment: +1 for the point about the ents. That's actually a pretty solid out-of-universe answer right there...

Comment: I don't fault Jackson for making changes - he did a great job adapting a very well known, deeply loved, wildly expansive saga to the movie screen.  It is a very difficult and intimidating prospect to adapt books with such a fanatical following, and asking modern audiences to sit in a theater for over 3 hours at a time is unheard of.  I might feel differently if I had read the books before I saw the movies, but as I read them now for the first time, I am coming to love each version - movies and books - in its own way, on its own merits, and for very different reasons.

Comment: @AcePL - Changes you attribute to "delusion" are actually part of keeping people engaged with a movie for over 3 hours straight (an unheard of amount of time nowadays). Excitement and dramatic effect are the name of the game, hence the Rohirrim saving the day with a dramatic entry at the last second. Or the emotionally powerful appearance of the Elves to honor the old alliance between Elves and Men. Logical?  No. Compelling (at least to those who haven't read the books)? Very. Films and books face different restraints and liberties. What works on the page doesn't work on film and vice versa.

Comment: @Wad Cheber: It's perhaps worth noting that even Tolkien falls down pretty badly on some things, for instance when it comes to horses.  E.g. Gandalf & Pippin are supposed to have ridden from Isengard to Minas Tirith - something over 500 miles - without stopping to let Shadowfax graze or rest!  And without even a saddle :-(  For a real-world comparison, see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endurance_riding

Comment: @jamesqf I raised similar concerns about horse stamina in regards to a different question.  The Rohirrim in the movies seem to gallop from Rohan to Gondor nonstop, a trip of several hundred miles.  A horse with a rider and his gear can gallop at top speed for less than a mile in the real world, and gallop slower (i.e., not a full sprint) for maybe an additional mile after that.

Comment: @jamesqf For that matter, the Rohirrim ride horses long distances, then assemble and launch their cavalry charge on the same horses. This was NEVER done in medieval times- you rode one set of horses, got to the battlefield, dismounted, mounted the fresh horses, and rode those into the battle. They weren't even the same kind of horse: for travel, you wanted a strong horse with a steady smooth gait but for fighting you needed a fearless, agile and aggressive horse that wouldn't veer off for a charge or throw the rider to avoid slamming into the enemy. Strength and stamina vs. bursts of activity

Comment: @Wad Cheber: Yes, and if you were a Mongol-like horse people (and the Rohirrim seem to be closer to an Aryan version of them, rather than Medieval knights) you traveled with perhaps half a dozen horses for each fighter.  Though I must admit that I never noticed any of this the first time I read the books, decades ago.  It was only re-reading them after some years of owning horses myself that the discrepancies popped out at me.

Comment: @WadCheber - orcs don't LIKE sun. It's "psychological" only. Do not mix orcs and trolls (who can't stand it). So daylight is no problem. Delusional - like I said: he "improved" on the story. 3 hrs of movie is bad screenwriting. PERIOD. Add bad translation for the screen (movie operates with pictures, which can condense pages and pages of description into just one second of runtime WELL) and you get pretty crap. jamesqf - and in book they rode on different horses IIRC. Weren't Eowyn "supposed to stay with the horses" in the book? Also Shadowfax was not a horse...

Comment: @AcePL - it does seem that Orcs dislike the sun rather than being physically affected by it, but one of the Moria Orcs says "We CAN'T run in daylight" - still, after Ugluk starts getting stabby, the Moria Orcs manage to run in the daylight well enough, but we are told that ALL the Orcs begin running much faster after sunset.  Sunlight seems to affect Orcs the same way that the gloomy menacing old forest affected the hobbits - they have less energy, are given to despair and emotional weariness, etc.

Comment: @AcePL: Shadowfax WAS a horse.  An older breed of horse, stronger (and perhaps larger) than contemporary horses, but still a horse.  We do see troops of Rohirrim with single horses, as when Eomer's troop comes upon Aragorn, Legolas, & Gimli when they're following the orc-captured hobbits, and 'conveniently' have just two or three extra horses, because their riders were killed in the fight.  As to the movie, I'd argue that if Jackson couldn't translate the book well, then he shouldn't have released the bad translation that he did.

Comment: @jamesqf: OK, then Shadowfax was to the horses of Rohan Like Aragorn was to humans. So in a way, yes. But not exactly.

Comment: @AcePL: Sure.  A very strong, well-trained horse (perhaps similar to modern endurance-racing horses), but still a horse.  Just as Aragorn was a very strong, well-trained warrior, but still human.  For comparison, consider for instance that Pony Express stations were located about 10 miles apart, that being the distance that a fairly lightly-burdened horse could travel at speed.

Comment: @jamesqf: Not really... Tolkien writes about a lot of different kinds of Man. And, for example about Aragorn Tolkien wrote a bit, especially about his height, strength, endurance and other characteristics. And remember, he was 87. Compare to Théoden who was probably 63-64. And Shadowfax was one of the Mearas (described to be to a normal horse like an Elf to a Third Age man). So, not really...

Comment: +1 for "Jackson delusions". I still lament what he has done to the dwarves. Short-range sprinters indeed.

Comment: @WadCheber That's because (1) he had Christopher help him with the maps; and (2) he made the maps first. Definitely he put a lot of time and thought and effort into it but making the maps first helped that a great deal. Having that foresight really was key.

Comment: @WadCheber To be fair to Richard - and painfully PJ - the distance in the films had to be condensed. Just like the time between Bilbo’s party and Frodo’s departure. Not saying PJ did good at all but this is something even I as a purist can forgive him for. Of course...the fact I cannot forgive him for everything. Well let’s just say the last time I tried watching the films I didn’t get through the second. How I managed as far as I did in that I do not know but I imagine I couldn’t now. The films are absolutely atrocious to say the least.

Comment: @jamesqf To be fair Shadowfax is not like the horses we have today and so it’s unfair to compare them to each other. And his original name is, translated, iirc Firefoot which might suggest something. But put another way the horses in The L.R. &c cannot be compared fairly. And if you try doing so what about the Nazgûl vultures? Those aren’t realistic either. We are talking about fantasy, after all...

Comment: @Pryftan: "...what about the Nazgûl vultures?"  Vultures?  No, Quetzalcoaltus northropi, plus a bit of artistic license: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetzalcoatlus  Read Tolkien's description  Also remember that the Ringwraiths are just that, wraiths, with a lot of their substance eaten away, so they're much lighter than a human of the same stature.

Comment: @jamesqf Want to wager a bet on that one? What about this from the letters? *Did the Witch-king ride a pterodactyl at the siege of Gondor?* **Pterodactyl. Yes and no. I did not intend the steed of the Witch-king to be what is now called a 'pterodactyl', and often is drawn (with rather less shadowy evidence that than lies behind many monsters of the new and fascinating semi-scientific mythology of the 'Prehistoric'). But obviously it is pterodactylic and owes much to the mythology, and its description even provides a sort of way in which it could be a last survivor of older geological eras.**

Comment: @jamesqf Furthermore in The Lord of the Rings it's suggested they are vultures and it's also in HoMe. So you're completely wrong on that (it was woefully ignoring my point too). And although I'm uncertain on their 'substance' I fail to see how relevant that is to my comments or anything for that matter. Exactly because it isn't relevant in the slightest. What was my point? **It's unrealistic as it's fantasy and people are trying to make it make sense?!** Sorry but that's just ... crazy.

Comment: @jamesqf So I remember at least in one reference besides HoMe anyway; either way when I say vulture in HoMe it's demonic vultures; and there are other comparisons to vultures too. The description is similar to a vulture too, for the creature. Either way it's (1) irrelevant to my point; (2) obviously not a vulture as we know it; and (3) you might say that in fact the best way to call it is as he suggested in the letter: **Pterodactylic**. Whatever you want to call it though they're unrealistic so trying to reason how they can fly so fast (etc.) is also unrealistic and frankly absurd.

Comment: @Pryftan:  Well, I defer to the description in LOTR. "...it was a winged creature: if bird, then greater than all other birds, and it was naked, and neither quill nor feather did it bear, and its vast pinions were as webs of hide between horned fingers; and it stank. A creature of an older world maybe it was..."  IIRC, where the Nazgul are described as vulture-like, it's more a description of behavior than of the nature of their mounts.

Comment: @jamesqf More correctly it's about the Nazgûl themselves. But (a) I suggested vulture because of HoMe; (b) I had this memory of them described as vultures (in one edition - but with all that's going on I could very well be mixing it up with something else); and (c) the way they're described could be *interpreted* as a vulture. Of course (d) is the interesting trivia from the letters. Point of it all is there are reasons I used the word 'vulture' and it's also valid; it's arguably however neither wrong nor right.

Comment: Insulting Peter Jackson for not making a film exactly the same as the book doesn't really add anything useful to this answer.

Answer (score 5):

When I was in the IDF, we did a 37 mile "march" (more like a jog) in 16 hours or so. For us humans (with a lot of gear on us and carrying some of our guys on stretchers over our heads) that would mean something like 2+ full days to cover the 100 miles you are talking about. Clearly though, we aren't talking about regular humans. As has been pointed out, Aragorn, Legolas, and Gimli had a very hard time trying to keep up with a group of orcs when they captured Mary and Pippin. Also, historically, warriors wouldn't carry as much as what modern infantry carries, so they would be able to move faster. I'd figure the total weight of equipment for Saruman's orcs was probably half what we had to haul around, and the half orcs (Saruman used human-orc hybrids) would be stronger than normal humans.

So, if they carry half what we did and they are stronger than us and basically don't stop for rests, I could see a half-orc army on foot making 100 miles in one day. It would be a hell of a march though.

Comment: Aragorn, Gimli and Legolas actually did remarkably well and if they didn't need to sleep they maybe would have caught up. But Gimli was stout, Legolas an Elf and Aragorn - well you know even besides the fact he was a Ranger (indeed that's what his kin is - Rangers). Not that Elves sleep in the same way...